# Leak at base of sliding glass door

Tags: leak, sliding-glass-door

I have a recently installed sliding glass door. I've been fighting with a leak for the past few months (photo 1). I've tried caulking along some exterior seams but that hasn't fixed anything. Today I noticed water pooling in the inside track (photo 2, hard to see but it's there). There is only one weep hole (photo 3, pointing at it with a paint brush) for the inside track.

My question is this. If the water isn't draining to the weep hole, is it simply slinking through the joint where the sill and jamb come together? If so, should I caulk that joint? Drill a new weep hole closer to said joint?
[image: Photo 1 - Leak location][[image: Pooling water inside trackweep hole location][image: weep hole location][image: Exterior of door][image: Exterior of door #2]

Comment: Oops, there is no photo 3

Answer (score 0):

Sliding doors are not waterproof. They should have some type of roof or awning over them to protect them from heavy rain.

That said, the jambs and sill should be caulked well from the factory. If you believe the water is seeping in from those areas, definitely add caulk.

Your pics show water had infiltrated between the side of the door and the wall.
If that area was not addressed when the new door was installed, it needs to be.

You don't show any pics from the outside, so no advice there, but telling us that water is in the bottom sill, tells me rain is hitting the door. You may do well to plan for some type of roof above the slider to protect it better.

Comment: Thank you RMDman! I added that 3rd photo that you pointed out was missing, as well as two from the exterior. Maybe an awning addition over the door is a project that is in my future. I do have a follow up question for you, if you'd be so kind. When you say..."Your pics show water had infiltrated between the side of the door and the wall. If that area was not addressed when the new door was installed, it needs to be."... What exactly would addressing that area look like? Adding or replacing window/door flashing? Thanks again for all the info, really appreciated.

Comment: Tree debris could be blocking the weep holes. I understand that trees and wind conspire against you.  That can be another reason to consider an awning.  The interior pic shows what looks like mold on the wall to the left of the door.  That is a warning of water infiltration.  Adding the exterior pictures shows an electric outlet and light outside. The water infiltration can be coming from around that outlet and/ or light. Especially since there is no roof or awning protecting it.